# Get everything before and after a character

Tags: mysql

I have 2 rows that contain strings like this :

```
AX/Aland Island No.5/7865.43/5212.62

KR/Republic of Korea/4-08-2021/8-09-2021
```

I want everything after two first slashes '/' and before the last slash '/'.

I want my result to be:

```
20142.87
19-02-2022
```

I know that we can use functions like substring and charindex but I still don't understand how the syntax is. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: there is no row that has such a condition, even though the strings are different but the string I need is still located  after two first slashes '/' and before the last slash '/'. Just like the example shown @AaronBertrand
i use SQL Server 2014

Comment: @Sarada Will the value be only numbers (always) after the first two slashes ? and also won't the string in between the first two slashes start with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string between the first two slashes will not start with an integer whatsoever and the string after the first 2 slashes is always going to start with an integer then below is the solution.

```
declare @tbl table(string varchar(200))

insert into @tbl
values('AX/Aland Island No.5/20142.87/20542.87')
,('KR/Republic of Korea/19-02-2022/19-03-2022')

select SUBSTRING(string,PATINDEX('%[/][0-9]%',string)+1,
CHARINDEX('/',SUBSTRING(string,PATINDEX('%[/][0-9]%',string)+1,len(string)))-1)
from
@tbl
```